# How to edit default alert mails?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alert

I came across a problem that I can't send emails via a distribution group. I want to modify default email alert and push it out using outlook rules but can't find where to edit an alert template. Maybe there is a way to create a new template for a specific alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to SharePoint farm servers you can change layout of alert for entire farm or create your custom template as described here - 
[Alert template from scratch](http://www.ludovicperrichon.com/alert-template-from-scratch/)

Comment: I don't have access to it. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I think - not. It should be done on server side.

Answer (score 0):

To customize the default format of alert mails, you are able to modify an XML file called alerttemplates.xml located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML.

Here is an article about modify the appearance and email body of alerts for your reference:

http://jimecox.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/modifying-the-appearance-and-email-body-of-alerts/